# Java: Get values in a range from a collection

Tags: java, collections

Suppose I have a (sorted) collection, be that a List, a Map, a Set or anything else. What would be the best solution to get all the values within a certain range.

For instance I have a list of Integers like so: [1, 5, 7, 9, 12, 30, 50, 100]

I would like to retrieve the 8 +- 5 values, which is going to be: [5, 7, 9, 12]

I know about the NavigableMap which is quite interesting, however I can only retrieve one element using it.

Do you have any tips on an algorithm that has a better complexity than O(N), maybe O(NLogN) or a specific collection I could use?

Thanks very much!
Costi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest to what you're looking for is a `NavigableSet`, which has the [following method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet%28E,%20boolean,%20E,%20boolean%29):

```
NavigableSet<E> subSet(E fromElement,
                   boolean fromInclusive,
                   E toElement,
                   boolean toInclusive)
```

If you have a sorted list, then using `Collections.binarySearch()` twice would allow you to quickly find the index of the first and last elements in the range.

Also, note that if what you need is a Map, `NavigableMap` has a [similar method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29).

Comment: "using Collections.binarySearch() twice" What does each run do? When us this done?

Comment: The first one looks for the index of the start of the range, and the second one looks for the index of the end of the range. Once you have the two indices, you use subList() to get all the alements in the range. This is more complex though, because binarySearch sometimes returns negative values, and doesn't provide guarantees when duplicate values exist, so you need a bit of code to make that work corrrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sorted array, you can binary search the min of the range, then binary search the max of the range in O(log(n)).